# Bootstrap v5: Column elements become farther apart on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

On my widescreen monitor, my cover page looks like this (which is how I want it to look):
[image]

But on my smaller screen laptop, the words and the buttons (which are each in two separate columns) get spread out and my cover page looks like this:

[image]

I've tried several things but I can't seem to get them to stick together on smaller screens. Here is the relevant HTML code:

**HTML**:

```
  <div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center g-0">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="title">transfer your</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="title">music</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="subtitle">between Spotify & YouTube</h2>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row mb-3">
            <a class="btn" id="sp-to-yt" href="#" role="button">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <a class="btn" id="yt-to-sp" href="#" role="button">
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on a percentage width. You can use the responsive classes to manage each screen size.

For small screens use `<div class="col-sm-6"></div>` which will display half-width on small screens. You can use multiple responsive classes like so...

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-3 col-xl-4"></div>`

The responsive elements can be remembered as sm = small, md = medium, lg = large, etc, and will control each breakpoints div widths. Remember the max number of columns by default is 12.

Also, in your row.. `<div class="row d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center g-0">` you don't need to define the display flex as .row is already a display flex class.